# Running a fine & working code through a loop doesn't work

Tags: r, regex, loops

From the string:

```
"((VBD)(((JJ))(CC)((RB)(JJ)))((IN)((DT)(JJ)(NNP)(NNPS))))"
```

I needed the following:

```
"JJ", "RBJJ", "DTJJNNPNNPS", "JJCCRBJJ", "INDTJJNNPNNPS" "VBDJJCCRBJJINDTJJNNPNNPS"
```

(this was my earlier query on SO, which was solved by @Brian Diggs. Please refer to "R : how to differentiate between inner and innermost brackets using regex", if necessary)

so I Used the following code:

```
library("plotrix")
library("plyr")
strr<-c("((VBD)(((JJ))(CC)((RB)(JJ)))((IN)((DT)(JJ)(NNP)(NNPS))))")
tmp <- gsub("\\(([^\\(\\)]*)\\)",  '("\\1")', strr)
tmp <- gsub("\\(", "list(", tmp)
tmp <- gsub("\\)list", "),list", tmp)
tmp <- eval(parse(text=tmp))
atdepth <- function(l, d) {
if (d > 0 & !is.list(l)) {
 return(NULL)
}
 if (d == 0) {
 return(unlist(l))
 }
if (is.list(l)) {
 llply(l, atdepth, d-1)
 }
 }

 pastelist <- function(l) {paste(unlist(l), collapse="", sep="")}
 down <- llply(1:listDepth(tmp), atdepth, l=tmp)
 out <- if (length(down) > 2) {
 c(unlist(llply(length(down):3, function(i) {
 unlist(do.call(llply, c(list(down[[i]]), replicate(i-3, llply), pastelist)))
 })), unlist(pastelist(down[[2]]))) 
 } else {
 unlist(pastelist(down[[2]]))
 }
 out <- out[out != ""]
```

And I got what I wanted, But Is it not possible to use the above code through a loop to process multiple strings (strr etc.) at the same time? I roughly need a bunch of strings to be processed and collected in a file. I'm trying to include a loop, but always end up in having just the last string from the set of strings in the out file. How should I run the code through a loop? The string set below.

```
strr<-c("(((((NNS))((IN)((NNS)(CC)(NNS))))((VBD)((PRP))((IN)((NN))))))", 

"((((NNS))((VBD)((TO)(((NNP))((NNP))))((TO)((DT)(NNP))))))", 

"((((IN)(((NNP))((NNP))))((NNP)(NNP)(NNPW)(NNP))((VBD)((IN)((DT)(JJ)(NN)(NN))))))"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly it could be modified in a more clever way, but a straightforward one would be to define a new function and use `sapply()`

```
### Nothing new
library("plotrix")
library("plyr")
strr<-c("(((((NNS))((IN)((NNS)(CC)(NNS))))((VBD)((PRP))((IN)((NN))))))", 
        "((((NNS))((VBD)((TO)(((NNP))((NNP))))((TO)((DT)(NNP))))))",   
        "((((IN)(((NNP))((NNP))))((NNP)(NNP)(NNPW)(NNP))((VBD)((IN)((DT)(JJ)(NN)(NN))))))")

strrr <- strr[rep(1:3,200)]

atdepth <- function(l, d) {
  if (d > 0 & !is.list(l)) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  if (d == 0) {
    return(unlist(l))
  }
  if (is.list(l)) {
    llply(l, atdepth, d-1)
  }
}
pastelist <- function(l) {paste(unlist(l), collapse="", sep="")}
###
### New function here
fun <- function(strr){
tmp <- gsub("\\(([^\\(\\)]*)\\)",  '("\\1")', strr)
tmp <- gsub("\\(", "list(", tmp)
tmp <- gsub("\\)list", "),list", tmp)
tmp <- eval(parse(text=tmp))

down <- llply(1:listDepth(tmp), atdepth, l=tmp)
out <- if (length(down) > 2) {
  c(unlist(llply(length(down):3, function(i) {
    unlist(do.call(llply, c(list(down[[i]]), replicate(i-3, llply), pastelist)))
  })), unlist(pastelist(down[[2]]))) 
} else {
  unlist(pastelist(down[[2]]))
}
out <- out[out != ""]
out
}

sapply(strr, fun)
```